# After merging a repo into another repo, git push fails due to bad committer data (Complaining about commits by other users from repo A)

Tags: git, repository, git-merge, git-commit, git-push

I merged the master branch of repo A into repo B feature branch locally.

Master Branch of Repo A has 1000's of commits by many different committers.

I followed the general merge guidances like this https://gist.github.com/msrose/2feacb303035d11d2d05

However, when I try to push to the origin, it rejects it by saying it has bad committer data, it is basically saying the commits that came from the repo A by many committers dont match my commit credentials.

```
"XXXX <XXX@XXXX.com>" does not match your
remote: credentials. You are logged in as: "YYYY <YYYY@YYYYY.com>".
```

Just for context, XXXX is the last committer on repo A master branch that I merged into repo B.

How do I solve this ? I would think the whole point of being able to merge 2 different repositories would be to preserve the commit history.

When I look up git log locally, it is showing all the commit history of both the repositories as expected in the right order.

Comment: Where are you pushing?

Comment: Pushing to the origin, that is my bitbucket repository.

Comment: Self-hosted Bitbucket or bitbucket.org? (They are not the same, but whichever one is rejecting the push is what's causing this.)

Comment: Basically, it is my companies bitbucket

Comment: Looks like I may have to change the commiter of each commit to myself to own the repository merges according to company policy.

Comment: It seems your bitbucket has enabled a security check which does not allow a user to push commits of another person. There should be a setting value that allows you to do so.

Comment: As said in other comments: there is a specific pre-receive hook set up on your company's hosted repository. Check with your company (your team leader ? your git admin ?) if your use case could skip over this specific check, or if you need to add one commit with your name on it, or if you need to rewrite all commits to change the committer.